# View Serializability

Tags: database, concurrency, database-concurrency

If a schedule of transactions is not view-serialisable, can we conclude that the schedule is non-serialisable?

In other words, is it possible for a schedule to be serialisable and yet not view serialisable?

If possible, please give an example.